# how to access another application's text field in electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I wanna make an electron application which needs to access to another application's input field so that I can change those texts to my String variable.

For example,
If my electron application is running in background and I made a test string

`let str = "test string"`

and I am on the another applications which has an input field and I'm putting some texts.
Then, when I press specific key which is set by accelerator, I want to change my texts specific words to my variable `str`

Comment: electronjs can't interfere another application's behavior. Except for keyboard action with globalShortcut.

Comment: If you want to just replace a string, it can be done with clipboard modification. Select string which you want to replace, and then change clipboard content via electronjs triggered by globalShortcut and paste "text" which you want using Ctrl+V

Comment: Looks like what you're attempting to do requires some kind of interaction with OS specific APIs and can only be done with help of native add-ons.